# I'm trying to customize a centered popup window in a vue project, but the web page has a lot of blank space

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to customize a centered popup in a vue project, but I'm running into a weird problem. This is what I've done so far:

[image]

In the lower right corner of the web page, there is a lot of blank space.

[image]

Also, I feel like the popup is not really centered, but a little to the right.

These are my popup related codes.

window.js

```js
import WindowApp from "./WindowApp"
import {createApp} from "vue"

export default {
    install(app) {
        const windowElement = document.createElement("div")
        // This is electron project, STORE is the Vuex store object, I set it in the global object: gloable.STORE = createStore({...})
        const windowApp = createApp(WindowApp).use(STORE).mount(windowElement)
        document.body.appendChild(windowElement)
        app.config.globalProperties.$showSettings = () => windowApp.proxySettings = true
    }
}
```

WindowApp.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <proxy-settings v-if="this.proxySettings" @close="this.proxySettings = false"></proxy-settings>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProxySettings from "./ProxySettings"

export default {
  name: "WindowApp",
  data() {
    return {
      proxySettings: false
    }
  },
  components: {
    ProxySettings
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="less">
</style>
```

ProxySettings.vue

```
<template>
  <center-window>
    <!--Some expressive controls.-->
    ...
  </center-window>
</template>

<script>
import CenterWindow from "./CenterWindow"
...

export default {
  name: "ProxySettings",
  components: {CenterWindow, ...},
  ...
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="less">
...
</style>
```

CenterWindow.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="InlineWindow">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InlineWindow",
  props: ["width", "height"]
}
</script>

<style scoped lang="less">
@import "../../css/variable";

.background {
  background-color: rgba(#000000bd);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.InlineWindow {
  @width: 400px;
  @height: 320px;

  border: @crudeBorder;
  background-color: @backgroundColor;
  width: @width;
  height: @height;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50vh - @width / 2);
  left: calc(50vw - @height / 2);
}
</style>
```

What I can determine is that those white spaces don't have any DOM elements, nor are they supposed to expand for an element's margins.why is that?

This is the environment of the project and the framework used:

browser: electron v17.0.1

vue: 3.2.30

element-plus: 2.0.1

element-plus/icons-vue: 0.2.7

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, it's an oversight of mine:

ProxySettings.vue:

```
<template>
...
<template/>

<script>
<script/>

<style lang="less" scope>
...
margin: 20px;
width: calc(100vw - 2 * @contentDistance);
height: calc(100vh - 2 * @contentDistance);
...
<style>
```

The values for width and height are wrong.the correct one is:

```css
width: calc(50vw - 2 * @contentDistance)
height: calc(50vh - 2 * @contentDistance)
```